# Simple C program crashes on windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, recursion, memory-leaks

I wrote a simple c program to simulate a memory leak. But it crashes when i try to run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void memory_leak(void);

int main()
{
    memory_leak();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void memory_leak()
{
    int i = 100;
    memory_leak();
}
```

I use MinGW gcc compiler.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Infinite loops tend to do that

Comment: I would rename `memory_leak()` to `stackoverflow()` :)

Comment: Why do you think that's a memory leak?  And where's the "YHBT HAND" close option?

Comment: It would be strange if a crash did not happen!

Comment: You have a recursive call to `memory_leak()`. That's going to eventually run in to a stack overflow. At least give it an exit condition.
`void memory_leak(int i){ if(i > 0) memory_leak(--i); else return; }`

Comment: @immibis i expected it to slowly rise memory usage i see in task manager.

Comment: Use a while loop to allocate an array without freeing it.

Comment: @Warix3 How about rising very *quickly*, then crashing once it hits a certain limit (I believe 1MB stack space by default)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are producing a stack overflow - by calling your function `memory leak` recursively.

Your version of `memory_leak` allocates a local ("stack") variable that will be released/destroyed/deallocated when the function exits.

To actually create a memory leak, you need to allocate memory from the heap (e.g. using `new` or `malloc`).

```
void* memory_leak()
{
    return malloc(10);
}
```

[Don't unconditionally call `memory_leak` within `memory_leak`.]

Comment: Thanks, that did what i actually wanted .

Comment: But it stopped on 2,035.1 MB. Is that system limit for a program or something? Because i still have 4.3 GB available memory.

Comment: What operating system are you testing?

Comment: i use Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Is your app a 32-bit application? If it is, 2GB is max for process (if not using "extensions" like AWE/4GT).  (System uses upper 2GB).  If 64-bit, check compiler switch /LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  It can also depend on static or dynamic linkage to the CRT.

Comment: It's a 32 bit application , how do i compile it in 64 bit one ?

Comment: Are you using Visual studio? If so, find the configuration manager and select 'x64' (you may have to create one... from the x86 version).

Comment: No I use notepad++ and a c compiler from MinGW.

Comment: Alas, I am not familiar with your compiler. This should be easy to solve though.